# How to turn vector

Tags: math-mode, diagrams, arc

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
\clip(-0.07329043126526,-0.796492988559363) rectangle (9.967791037095613,9.97807138066155);
\draw [->,line width=2pt] (0,5)--(10,5) ;
\draw [->,line width=2pt] (5,0) -- (5,10);
\draw [shift={(10-5,5.001014801310472)},line width=2pt,color=ffqqqq]  plot[domain=1.5707963267948966:2.8257080879245375,variable=\t]({1*2.4229434178792486*cos(\t r)+0*2.4229434178792486*sin(\t r)},{0*2.4229434178792486*cos(\t r)+1*2.4229434178792486*sin(\t r)});
\draw [->,line width=2pt,color=ffqqqq] (2.696939088106593,5.7537200838434694) -- (2.544859707985099,5);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (10,9.833835474935935) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (7.00904720302078,9.489934628472703) node {\Large {$Fork$}};
\draw [fill=black] (5.674489813878187,5) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.399712145615680487,4.03933260822143) node {\Large {$Noodle$}};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

i need to turn this red arc another side don't changing starting point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's truly a high level of automatization: upload inkscape generated figures here for fine tuning.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,bending}
\definecolor{ffqqqq}{RGB}{255,0,0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>={Triangle[bend]},x=0.5cm,y=0.5cm]
\clip(-0.07329043126526,-0.796492988559363) rectangle (9.967791037095613,9.97807138066155);
\draw [->,line width=2pt] (0,5)--(10,5) ;
\draw [->,line width=2pt] (5,0) -- (5,10);
\draw [<-,shift={(10-5,5.001014801310472)},line width=2pt,color=ffqqqq] (0,2) arc(90:180:2);
\draw [fill=black] (10,9.833835474935935) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (7.00904720302078,9.489934628472703) node[font=\Large] {Fork};
\draw [fill=black] (5.674489813878187,5) circle (0.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (1.399712145615680487,4.03933260822143) node[font=\Large] {Noodle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "That's truly a high level of automatization": is this meant positively or negatively?

Comment: imagine the intersection of black vectors(0,0) .  red vector should start from (0.1)  & end at (1,0) .   thank you any way.

Comment: @levan `\draw [->,shift={(10-5,5)},line width=2pt,color=ffqqqq] (0,2) arc(90:00:2);`

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner The interpretation is up to you.

Comment: thank you marmot.